# iterating over class object's attribute list throws python str error

Tags: python, json, serialization

What I'm trying to do is serialize some class objects using python. However when I attempt to iterate over a list attribute of a class object i get a str error. I'm not clear on how to fix this. I'm rather new to python.

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'serialize'

The error occurs inside the Family class object inside this function...

```
for member in self.members:
    print member
    data["members"].append( member.serialize() ) # ERROR
```

**The code**

```
import json


# Functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def GetProperties(properties):
    if properties == "Basic Properties":
        return { 
            "Basic Properties" : [
                Property("isMale", False),
                Property("isRelated", True),
            ]
        }
    elif properties == "Extra Properties":
        return { 
            "Extra Properties" : [
                Property("isTall", False),
                Property("isAthletic", True),
            ]
        }

# Classes
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Property:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, attributes={}):
        self.name = name
        self.attributes = {}

    def serialize(self):
        data = {
            "classname" : self.__class__.__name__,
            "name" : self.name,
            "attributes" : {},
        }
        return data


class Family:
    def __init__(self, name, members=[], attributes={}):
        self.name = name
        self.members = members[:]
        self.attributes = {}

    def serialize(self):
        data = {
            "classname" : self.__class__.__name__,
            "name" : self.name,
            "attributes" : {},
            "members" : [],
        }

        for member in self.members:
            print member
            data["members"].append( member.serialize() )

        return data


# testing Serialization
newPerson = Person( "Joey" )
newPerson.attributes.update( GetProperties( "Basic Properties" ) )

newFamily = Family( "Johnson's" )
newFamily.attributes.update( GetProperties( "Basic Properties" ) )
newFamily.members.append( "newPerson" )

data = newFamily.serialize()
json.dump(data, open("test.json",'w'), indent=4)
```

Comment: `newFamily.members.append( newPerson)`?  You had "newPerson" as a string literal.

Comment: darn you are correct. my stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
newFamily.members.append( newPerson)   # newPerson as the object instantiated in preceding lines
```

In your original code, you had:

```
newFamily.members.append("newPerson")  # newPerson as a string literal
```

So, passing the string, you are attempting to serialize the string, not the `Person` object.